# Error with mvn install local jar: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin...(Is a directory) -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin, maven-install-plugin

i am trying to install a local jar to my maven project, i am running this command from my project folder :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile= ~/Downloads/<jar_path> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project my-project: Error installing artifact 'my-artifact': Failed to install artifact groupId:artifactId:jar:version: /Users/my-project-path (Is a directory) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Did you try to put the exact jar file instead of the path of your project?

Comment: Have you tried to set `-DlocalRepositoryPath` ?

Comment: thank you for your answer guys but it was the space after -Dfile=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a space in your command, after `-Dfile=`!

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile= ~/Downloads/<jar_path> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false
```

try

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=~/Downloads/<jar_path> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false
```

Comment: Oh my god!!!! i can't believe this was it, i spent 5 hours yesterday but i had also to change the ~ by /Users/.... but it was the space causing the error thank you very very much for your help you saved my day