# Error "The Specified Jar file not exists" when executed mvn install:install on my local jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3

I have a jar file local to my project and I need to install the jar as a 3rd party file or just install this jar using `mvn install:install` command so that the jar will be available in .m2 folder (under repositories) and later I can declare the dependency in pom.xml which will not throw error, tried to execute in different ways but throws the below error.

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5 .2:install-file
> (default-cli) on project sampl-project: The specified file
> 'E:\sample-11.jar' not exists

The below combinations I tried to run `mvn install:install` but failed miserably.

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=sample.groupId
> -DartifactId=samplefields -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11 -D file=E:\sample-11.jar -DgeneratePom=true
>
> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=sample-groupId
> -DartifactId=samplefields -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11 -D file=E:\sample-11.jar -DgeneratePom=true
>
> mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=sample.groupId"
> -DartifactId=samplefields -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11 -D file=E:\sample-11.jar -DgeneratePom=true
>
> mvn install:install-file "-DgroupId=sample.groupId"
> "-DartifactId=samplefields" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-Dversion=11" "-D
> file=E:\sample-11.jar" "-DgeneratePom=true"

Further, I also tried to place my jar in different locations and different names and run `maven install:install` but same error I get

[image]

Maven Version -

```
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
```

Links I gone thru, but they are of different issue:
[Error with mvn install local jar: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin...(Is a directory) -> [Help 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012191/error-with-mvn-install-local-jar-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-plugin)
[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605429/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-install-plugin2-4install)

Comment: Start to use a repository manager ...

Comment: @khmarbaise can you share the link or any source where I can get information about repository manager..

Comment: https://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus-repository?topnav=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I did was to mention the version and use extension (.jar) name also into the command and that created the issue.

Invalid Command:

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=sample.groupId -DartifactId=samplefields -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11 -D file=E:\sample-11.jar -DgeneratePom=true

Valid Command:

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=sample.groupId -DartifactId=samplefields -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11 -D file=E:\sample -DgeneratePom=true

`-11.jar` text removed from command and it worked flawless! Hope this helps someone out here.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. In this error you see that the name of the artifact is not found :

> the specified file 'E:\                 -11.jar' not exists.

2. make sure that you have the permission to copy this file.
3. for all commands, i see that you have an space between -D and the file=E:\sample-11.jar.

**So you shoud remove the space and run the command line like this :**

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=sample.groupId -DartifactId=samplefields -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11 -Dfile=E:\sample-11.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: There are no spaces anywhere in my command!